# ogrmerge cannot open input files specified as a pattern

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I have several geojson files which I am trying to merge using the [ogrmerge.py](https://www.gdal.org/ogrmerge.html) script. For some reason I am getting `ERROR: Cannot open *.geojson` when I run

```
ogrmerge.py -o merged.geojson *.geojson -f GeoJSON -single
```

The operation works perfectly when I execute

```
ogrmerge.py -o merged.geojson f1.geojson f2.geojson -f GeoJSON -single
```

Any ideas why the * pattern matching is not working?
I am on Win7 and using Python27 bundled with my OSGeo4W install.

Comment: does ogrmerge.py -f GeoJSON -single -o merged.geojson *.geojson work?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Your call was the first that I tried as that's how it was presented in the doc example. Then I changed to the order above to match the order the arguments were presented in the docs. Both produced same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer to this problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405652/passing-arguments-with-wildcards-to-a-python-script. Apparently it is specific to Windows as the command line does not expand wildcards.

I would like to point out that this issue has been fixed in the [GDAL project on Github](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/735bddcb536a04ab5845f0b24cd7fbf6cb0048fe#diff-b3b042486ccc8a04479d5bb2bd5bd928). It appears that my OSGeoW install uses an older version of the script which did not address this problem.